# Convert Zulu/GMT to Local TimeZone

Tags: php, date, datetime

I've a date in this format (GMT, ISO 8601) like this:

> 2015-02-19T01:00:00.000Z

And i want to convert it to local timezone like for example *Europe/Lisbon*

```
$date = new DateTime( '2015-02-19T01:00:00.000Z' , new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
$date->setTimezone( new DateTimeZone('Europe/Lisbon') );
echo $date->format('F j, Y');
```

But it returns day 19, and the expected day is 18, what i'm missing?

Comment: When generating DateTime object, second parameter (timezone) is ignored, if timezone is already specified in first parameter. See **note** on [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php). And like already said in the answer, currently timezone `Europe\Lisbon` is now in `+00:00` offset, so the same result should be expected, [demo](https://eval.in/285836).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am missing something here Europe/Lisbon is GMT so getting the same result is to be expected.

Comment: So in which timezone would be expected day 18?

Comment: (GMT-2) Cap Vert, and so on... Everything west of Europe until you hit the International Date Line.